# How to convert double value into string value

Tags: c#

I want to convert a double value into a string value, but when I am concatenating this `string(double)` value, it is changing the `.` to `,` and I can't manipulate this value. I tried to use `String.Replace` but didn't work too.

What I can do in this case. Here is my Code.

```
object[] campos = new object[1];
        campos[0] = (double)56.25566;

Parameters[1] = "gdinvdllo005.start.load.coleta.o(" + campos[0].ToString() + ")";
```

Comment: you should probably accept the highest voted user here

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like your thread has a culture which uses "," as the decimal separator. The simplest approach is probably to call `string.Format` specifying the invariant culture:

```
Parameters[1] = string.Format(
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    "gdinvdllo005.start.load.coleta.o({0})",
    campos[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your current culture uses a comma as decimal separator but you want to force a point. Then you can use [`NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=nu%2Cmberformatinfo.%2Cinvariantinfo) in [`double.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
double doubleValue = 56.25566;
string stringValue = doubleValue.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
Parameters[1] = "gdinvdllo005.start.load.coleta.o(" + stringValue + ")";
```